# Parked domain redirecting to wrong error404 page

Tags: redirect, domain

I have 3 different WordPress sites on my host provider in a linux shared hosting package.  The main domain is domain-a.com.  A secondary add-on domain is domain-b.com.  I have a parked domain domain-c.com that redirects to domain-b.com.

All are registered elsewhere and the a-record points to this host provider.  Here's the problem: when a user types domain-c.com it properly redirects to domain-b.com.  No problem there.  The problem occurs when a user types domain-c.com/something.html (anything that is not found on the domain-b.com). It produces my error404 page for domain-a.com, not domain-b.com.

I am told by the host providers (at the registrar and this host) that this is a WordPress issue because of the htaccess file and how WP resolves the domains.

I have tried a plugin named Simple 301 Redirects but it has no effect here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Larry

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .htaccess file? and do all three domains share a common virtual root?

Comment: This is the part the host provider says is causing the problem
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Also, I am unfamiliar with the term common virtual root.  So, I will guess here.  It is a shared hosting account.  There is one main domain with the account and we can add other add-on domains that are registered elsewhere and parked domains that can be directed to those add-on domains as well.  The error page that appears is for the main domain on the account though.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's WordPress' standard `.htaccess` file - because all the sites use a common virtual root (think single folder) all domains are using the `.htaccess` code. Basically you need to rewrite the code to use separate instructions for each domain e.g. this would send a request for `newdomain.com` to a specific page.

```
# Internally rewrite new domain home page requests to a specific page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /specific-page.html [L]
```